# How to remove Surface padding in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn, android-jetpack-compose-material3

In `LazyColumn` when we use `LazyListScope.items` with `Surface`. Inside multiple items there is extra padding on **TOP** and **BOTTOM**. I want to remove this padding. I am using `Surface` component of **Material 3**. **BOM** version is `compose_bom = "2022.11.00"`.

> Please don't suggest any **alpha** or **beta** version fix. If **Material 3** stable api don't have solution, then please suggest normal **Surface Material**.

**PreviewCreateListView**

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun PreviewCreateListView() {
    CreateListView()
}
```

**CreateListView**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun CreateListView() {
    val itemList = listOf(1, 2, 3)
    LazyColumn(
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp),
    ) {
        items(itemList) { item ->
            Surface(
                onClick = { },
                color = Color.Blue
            ) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    text = "$item",
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The M3 `Surface` with the `onClick` parameter has a **minimum touch target size** (`48.dp`) for accessibility. It will include extra space outside the component to ensure that they are accessible.

You can override this behaviour applying `false` to the `LocalMinimumInteractiveComponentEnforcement`. If it is set to `false` there will be no extra space.

Something like:

```
CompositionLocalProvider(
    LocalMinimumInteractiveComponentEnforcement provides false) {
    
    Surface(
        onClick = { },
        color = Color.Blue
    ) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            text = "$item",
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

**Note:** `LocalMinimumInteractiveComponentEnforcement` requires at least
M2 `1.4.0-alpha04` and M3 `1.1.0-alpha04`. Before you can use **`LocalMinimumTouchTargetEnforcement`** in the same way.

Comment: `Unresolved reference: LocalMinimumInteractiveComponentEnforcement` getting error.

Comment: @VivekModi My bad. With the M3 1.0.1 stable you have to use `LocalMinimumTouchTargetEnforcement`. Starting with M3 **1.1.0** it was changed to `LocalMinimumInteractiveComponentEnforcement`

Answer (score 1):

The `Surface` variant that you use, with a `onClick` parameter, enforces a minimum height for accessibility purposes, see this at line 221

[image: Surface]

If you want to remove the space, use the variant without the `onClick` argument and use a `Modifier.clickable` instead

```
@Composable
fun CreateListView() {
    val itemList = listOf(1, 2, 3)
    LazyColumn(
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp),
    ) {
        items(itemList) { item ->
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.clickable {  },
                color = Color.Blue
            ) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    text = "$item",
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Result]